# RxJava Observable onNext not called on second time

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit, google-places-api

I'm fairly new to RxJava. Recently I have been trying to implement a piece of code which retrieves list of places and their ids within the selected radius using Google Places Api and then retrieves the details of those places using the ids retrieved previously. I have a button in an activity which then calls the Api to retrieve the information. My problem is, the Api is called and data is emitted when the first time the button is clicked. On consecutive attempts the onNext isn't fired and only onComplete is called.

Here's the interface code I use to retrieve the list of places and their details using Retrofit

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET("api/place/nearbysearch/json?radius=5000&key="+API_KEY)
Observable<PlacesResponse> getPlaces(@Query("location") String location, @Query("types") String types);

@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@GET("api/place/details/json?key="+API_KEY)
Observable<PlacesDetailsResponse> getPlaceDetails(@Query("placeid") String placeId);
```

Then I use this to initiate the Api on my activity's onCreate method

```
private void initiateApi() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
    mapService = retrofit.create(MapAPI.class);
}
```

I have a search box in my activity and a button. When search query is entered and the button is clicked I call this method to first retrieve user's location, then get the ids of the places and finally the details of those places.

```
private void startPlaceFetchingTask(final String type) {
        showProgress();
        final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (mResponses == null) {
            mResponses = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        mResponses.clear();
        Observable.fromCallable(this::getSynchronousLocation)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .retryWhen(errors -> errors.flatMap(error -> {
                    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (error instanceof NullPointerException && (currentTime - startTime) < 30000) {
                        return Observable.timer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    }
                    return Observable.error(error);
                }))
                .flatMap(location -> {
                    mLocation = location;
                    String locationString = location.latitude + "," + location.longitude;
                    return mapService.getPlaces(locationString, type)
                            .map(response -> response.getResults())
                            .flatMap(results -> Observable.fromIterable(results))
                            .flatMap(result -> mapService.getPlaceDetails(result.getPlaceId()));
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(getObserver());
}
```

Here is what I use to retrieve the user's current location

```
private LatLng getSynchronousLocation() throws SecurityException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
    Location location = Tasks.await(mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation(), 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
}
```

and to get the observer

```
    private Observer<PlacesDetailsResponse> getObserver() {
        return new Observer<PlacesDetailsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                addDisposable(d);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(PlacesDetailsResponse placesDetailsResponse) {
                addPlace(placesDetailsResponse);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                //handle error
                hideProgress();
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                //do stuff
                hideProgress();
            }
        };
```

As I have said earlier, all of this is working fine when the app is opened and the search button is clicked the first time. If the button is clicked again, only onComplete is getting called and no data is being emitted on onNext.
I'd really appreciate if someone could point out what am I doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Here's is the addDisposable method, it adds the disposable to a Composite disposable and disposes during onDestroy.

```
private void addDisposable(Disposable disposable) {
    if (mDisposable == null) {
        mDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    }
    mDisposable.add(disposable);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mDisposable != null && !mDisposable.isDisposed()) {
        mDisposable.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `addDisposable` doing? Do you by any chance dispose a `CompositeDisposable` this `addDisposable` works with?

Comment: @akarnokd I'm adding the disposable object to a `CompositeDisposable` via `addDisposable` method and then disposing the `CompositeDisposable` on `onDestroy` event of the activity. I'm not disposing it anywhere else. I've added both methods for further clarification.

Comment: Put a breakpoint into `addDisposable`, click twice and see if `mDisposable` reports `isDisposed()` as true. If it is false, start adding `doOnSubscribe`s and `doOnNext`s that print something identifying that stage and see where events stop.

Comment: @akarnokd Sorry for the late response and thank you so much for your response. I've found out that when I press the button 2nd time, the places api sends a OVER_QUERY_LIMIT status. So I think I've to think of a better way to request so that it doesn't go over the query limit.